# sending pre populated sms from iPhone application

Tags: iphone

My requirements are like automatically sending a list to client through sms from my iPhone App. I did a little googling with no relevant result. all post are regarding opening sms editor using openUrl, but not about populating the content of sms using some text...

Answer (score 3):

This is supported:

```
sms:1-408-555-1212
```

From the [URL Scheme Reference](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008054)

But it notes the following:

> The URL string must not include any
>   message text or other information.

Comment: Hi Slf

Thanks for quick response...but this dosen't solve the problem.
The question remains same...how to include text with sms....?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible in the public SDK. The closest you can get is to launch the SMS application with a number pre-entered (via the `sms:` URL scheme)