# Can you prepopulate an SMS using sms: like mailto:?

Tags: mobile, sms

What I would like to do is pre populate an SMS similar to how you can populate the subject line of an email with `?subject` on `mailto:` links.

I don't want to automatically send the SMS, or the recipients, just the copy (which the user could edit). From what I've read it looks like `sms:` only allows by specifying the recipients, or nothing at all.

Can this be done with `sms:`? Or does it require native code (for iOS/Android)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Although this would be helpful for web developers, neither Android nor iOS allows this to be done through urls.

Apple has a list of recognized url schemes [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008054-SW1).

If you're developing an app with phonegap however, this can be done programmatically using plugins like SMSComposer for iOS and SMSPlugin for Android.

Answer (score 4):

The answer to this question is now yes. This:

```
sms://+19875550198;?&body=This%20is%20a%20test%20message.
```

works just fine in Messages on both iOS and macOS. Copy and paste that link into your browser to test it on your system. I haven't tested this on other systems, but based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38708066/1652620), `;?&` seems useful for cross-device compatibility.

An example of how we're using this can be seen in [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/159099/217314). Unfortunately I couldn't figure out a way to populate the optional subject field in iOS.