# SMS URI Schema for browsers

Tags: android, iphone, asp.net, blackberry

I am working on some mobile web application (which is in asp.net 3.5).In that I want to open the SMS Editor using the sms uri (sms:) but my client want to open the mobile SMS editor using sms uri with body text.I checking this with BlackBerry,iPhone,Android.

```
<a href="sms:+447787000000?body=hello">Send SMS</a>
```

this is working fine with BlackBerry but iPhone and Android is not supported.can anybody help me out please.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPhone doesn't accept any message text, it will only take in the phone number. You can see this here 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/sms.html

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6480533/1117760