# Android SMS sending using Phonegap/Cordova 3.1

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How do I send SMS using Cordova/Phonegap 3.1?

I have searched but all the tutorials/plugins seems to be outdated and the examples doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Here I share my working sms plugin. please try with this. I hope this will help you. If any issue let me know.

SmsPlugin.java

```
package org.apache.cordova.plugin;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsManager;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.api.PluginResult;

public class SmsPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    public final String ACTION_SEND_SMS = "SendSMS";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals(ACTION_SEND_SMS)) {
            try {               
                String phoneNumber = args.getString(0);
                String message = args.getString(1);
                String method = args.getString(2);

                if(method.equalsIgnoreCase("INTENT")){
                    invokeSMSIntent(phoneNumber, message);
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult( PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT));
                } else{
                    sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
                }

                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));
                return true;
            }
            catch (JSONException ex) {
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult( PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
            }           
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void invokeSMSIntent(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        this.cordova.getActivity().startActivity(sendIntent);
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.cordova.getActivity(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
        manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentIntent, null);
    }   
}
```

index.html

```
$(document).ready(function() {
             $("#btnDefaultSMS").click(function(){             
                var number = $("#numberTxt").val();
                var message = $("#messageTxt").val();
                SmsPlugin.prototype.send(number, message, 'INTENT',
                    function () { 
                       alert('Message sent successfully');  
                    },
                    function (e) {
                        alert('Message Failed:' + e);
                    }
                );               
             });            
         });
```

HTML Part

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
               <input name="" id="numberTxt" placeholder="Enter mobile number" value="" type="tel" data-mini="true"><br>
               <textarea name="" id="messageTxt" placeholder="Enter message" data-mini="false"></textarea>
               <br>
               <input id="btnDefaultSMS" type="submit" data-theme="e" value="Send SMS" data-mini="false">
               <input id="btnShare" type="submit" data-theme="e" value="Share" data-mini="false">
            </div>
```

smsplugin.js

```
var SmsPlugin = function () {};
SmsPlugin.prototype.send = function (phone, message, method, successCallback, failureCallback) {    
    return PhoneGap.exec(successCallback, failureCallback, 'SmsPlugin', "SendSMS", [phone, message, method]);
};

PhoneGap.addConstructor(function() {
    PhoneGap.addPlugin("sms", new SmsPlugin());
});
```

config.xml

```
<feature name="SmsPlugin">
      <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.plugin.SmsPlugin"/>
    </feature>
```

Comment: could you possibly send me a sample? A working project would be nice. Thanks

Comment: If my answer is correct, then accept it so that it will be useful for others. And just try with above code and configure properly. if have problem please let me know

Answer (score 1):

I'm sending SMSs from phonegap, using the native sms sender by creating a button with a link that uses the sms protocol, similar to [bradorego's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link) for another question:

```
<a href="sms:/* phone number here */?body=/* body text here */">Link</a>
```