# href sms: || smsto: not working on android with html+cordova(phonegap)

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building an android app using cordova and html(js/css etc..)
I'm trying to open the sms application when the user click on a link.

this is the html code:

```
<a href="sms:052xxxx808">Send Sms</a>
```

while the `tel:` and `mailto:` schemes works, the `sms:` or `smsto:` not working.

**INFO:**

using the `sms:` scheme I get this error: `No Activity found to handle Intent`

```
E/Cordova(28360): Error sending sms sms:052xxxx808:android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW typ=vnd.android-dir/mms-sms (has extras) }
```

And using the `sms:` scheme I get this error: `ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME`

```
D/Cordova(27207): CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-10 Description=net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME URL=smsto:052xxxx808
```

I'm using Nexus 5 with Kitkat 4.4.2 to test the app..

P.S: on Galaxy 4 the `sms:` scheme is working...(not KitKat)

**UPDATE:**

Clicking on a href link in the **browser** with the `sms:` scheme does work, So maybe I missing permission or something like that?

Comment: I can confirm I'm seeing the exact same thing and was just about to post the same when I found your report.  Have you tried using the Cordova SMS plugin instead the href? I was starting to go down that path.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working by creating an SMS Plugin that combined two previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19721772/android-sms-sending-using-phonegap-cordova-3-1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20079047/android-kitkat-4-4-hangouts-cannot-handle-sending-sms-intent). The only catch is that you have to check for the intent to see if build version is KitKat to do differently than in the past.

Here's my plugin code:

```
public class SmsPlugin extends CordovaPlugin {
    public final String ACTION_SEND_SMS = "SendSMS";

    @Override
    public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, final CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {
        if (action.equals(ACTION_SEND_SMS)) {
            try {
                String phoneNumber = args.getString(0);
                String message = args.getString(1);
                String method = args.getString(2);

                if (method.equalsIgnoreCase("INTENT")) {
                    invokeSMSIntent(phoneNumber, message);
                    callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.NO_RESULT));
                } else {
                    sendSMS(phoneNumber, message);
                }

                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK));
                return true;
            } catch (JSONException ex) {
                callbackContext.sendPluginResult(new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.JSON_EXCEPTION));
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void invokeSMSIntent(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        Intent intent;
        Activity activity = this.cordova.getActivity();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) // Android 4.4 and up
        {
            String defaultSmsPackageName = Telephony.Sms.getDefaultSmsPackage(activity);

            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:" + Uri.encode(phoneNumber)));
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);

            // Can be null in case that there is no default, then the user would be able to choose any app that supports this intent.
            if (defaultSmsPackageName != null) {
                intent.setPackage(defaultSmsPackageName);
            }
        } else {
            intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
            intent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
            intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
        }

        activity.startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message) {
        SmsManager manager = SmsManager.getDefault();
        PendingIntent sentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.cordova.getActivity(), 0, new Intent(), 0);
        manager.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, message, sentIntent, null);
    }
}
```

And here is how I invoke it from JavaScript:

```
var sms = function() {
    message: function (phnum, callback) {
        if (Ext.os.is.iOS) {
            cordova.exec(callback, function (err) {
                callback('The following error occurred: ' + err);
            }, "Sms", "send", [ {"recipients": [phnum]} ]);
        } else if (Ext.os.is.Android) {
            cordova.exec(callback, function (err) {
                callback('The following error occurred: ' + err);
            }, "SmsPlugin", "SendSMS", [phnum, "", "INTENT"] );
        } else {
            document.location.href = "sms:" + phnum
        }
    }
};
module.exports = sms;
```

Be sure to add this to you config.xml:

```
<feature name="SmsPlugin">
    <param name="android-package" value="my.plugin.SmsPlugin" />
</feature>
```