# How do I pre-populate the message body in OS X Messages app via hyperlink?

Tags: macos, sms, message, url-parameters

In OS X, the Messages app can be launched with a hyperlink to `messages:` or `imessage:`. I can add a phone number to the URL and it will open up a new message for that person. Is it possible to also pre-fill the message body in OS X?

For reference, in [iOS this is accomplished via adding &body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link) to the URL. I have tried &body, &compose, &message, &text, etc. in OS X without luck. Any ideas on how to prepopulate the message?

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't pre-fill out the body of the message text.  Probably some reason related to security.

[iMessage will take a userid](http://osxdaily.com/2012/05/15/start-an-imessage-conversation-from-the-web-with-custom-links/): `imessage://your@apple.id.com`

and Message opens up mail.  [The only parameter is a previous message ID](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54969/url-to-individual-email).  e.g. `message://<insert-your-message-id-here>`

[One thing you *could* do is try a `mailto:` URL](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/MailLinks/MailLinks.html).  That is, something like:

`mailto:foo@example.com?cc=bar@example.com&subject=Greetings%20from%20San%20Francisco!&body=Wish%20you%20were%20here!`

I just tried it in Firefox for MacOS and it works great!

Comment: You're correct that `message:` opens Mail, but `messages:` does open Messages. Found via this command: `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Support/lsregister -dump|egrep "(bindings.*\:$)"|sort`

Comment: And thanks for the OS X Daily link, although I'm not certain the article isn't outdated. At the time it was written, you couldn't pre-populate the message body in iOS, but as of iOS 8 it's doable. Am wondering if there was a similar change for OS X.