# SMS Link Not Working for Hangouts on Android

Tags: javascript, html, sms

The following SMS link does not seem to work on a Nexus in Hangouts, but works fine in the default Messaging app on a Samsung phone.

`<a href="sms:&body=Let\'s%20connect%20near">Link</a>`

I even tried adding a number before the URL, but no luck:

`<a href="sms:12345678&body=Let\'s%20connect%20near">Link</a>`

Any idea how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `?` instead of `&` since it's the first parameter. Tested it over my nexus and it worked correctly after this fix (I'm using Google Messenger App).

```
<a href="sms:?body=Let\'s%20connect%20near">Link</a>
```

**UPDATE:**

Another problem that you may have is that Hangouts doesn't support pre-populated sms message links.

Also, looks like you should use `&` for iOS devices.
[How to pre-populate the sms body text via an html link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link)

Comment: Hey @alebruck, thanks for your response. For some reason it is still not working for me. I am testing on Nexus 5, what about you? It just opens the Hangouts app with no pre-filled body message.

Comment: So, I'm using a nexus 5 device but my sms app is Messenger (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging&hl=en). To simulate your problem I changed my default sms app to Google Hangouts and turnout it really doesn't work. I researched a little and it's a problem with Google Hangouts, looks like it doesn't support pre-populated sms messages https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/hangouts/Xzm9ykjj20k.

Updating my answer to point that.

Comment: Yeah, same issue here. Works in Messenger, but not Hangouts. And I believe (or assume) most users are using Hangouts.