# Is it possible to attach a file to an MMS via an HTML link?

Tags: html, hyperlink, sms, mms

I read here that it's possible to prepopulate an SMS body text via an HTML link :

[How to pre-populate the sms body text via an html link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link)

Does anyone know if it's possible to add a Base64 image (becoming MMS) with a (e.g) "&attachment=" parameter ?

Something like :

```
<a href="sms:?body=/* body text here */&attachment=data:image/jpg;base64,/* Base64 image here */;"></a>
```

And if it's not, any idea how to do this ?

Thanks

Comment: The spec for the mms: protocol is at https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-wugofski-mms-uri-scheme-00, I'd start there