HTML link for send MMS message
In HTML, I can send SMS messages using links like so:
<a href="sms:+1-123-456-7890?body=Interested%20in%20your%20product">Sms Me!</a>

However, I need to send images with text (MMS message).
Is it possible to do this with an HTML link, or any other way?

Did you try? If there is an mms protocol handler (that will send instead of playing it) on the client, it should work. If not, not.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596475/is-it-possible-to-attach-a-file-to-an-mms-via-an-html-link

There is an mms: URI scheme that is somewhat supported, but it's not for MMS-messages, but instead the MMS stands for Microsoft Media Server. When I tested clicking on a mms: link in Chrome, it tried opening VLC. (MMS URL Scheme)
There is no URI scheme designated for Multimedia Messaging Service (Uniform Resource Identifier), and there is no way to attach an attachment using the sms: URI scheme (RFC 5724), so it is unfortunately not possible.

You could have the user host the image somewhere and paste the link, or you could have a image hosting service specifically for your website. (like SO)
