# SMS-links don't work on iOS 10.2

Tags: html, ios, iphone, sms, ios10

Seems that sms-links don't work after update of iOS to the 10.2 version.
All the following links don't work correctly. By click on them native app is open but seems it is trying to find the recipient in Contacts. As a result sms-app is frozen and no reaction to taps.

```
        <a href="sms:">SMS Link #1</a>
        <a href="sms:1-234-567-89-10">SMS Link #2</a>
        <a href="sms:+12345678910">SMS Link #3</a>
        <a href="sms://1-234-567-8910">SMS Link #4</a>
```

The same works on Android as expected.

Has anyone faced the same problem? Is any idea how to fix it?

Thanks all.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link