# Pre-populate SMS body via HTML link/URL in email

Tags: android, html, ios, email, anchor

I am using a custom application to trigger emails and SMS campaigns in pre-deteremined time slots. As per a requirement, I need to send an email containing an **link/URL** such that, upon clicking that **link/URL** the default SMS app of the phone opens with the body text and number pre-poppulated.

I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link), and created the following URL:

```
<a href='sms:54321;?&body=HELLO'>Click here</a>
```

I put this in a HTML file, and sent it across an email attachment. It worked fine on Android as well as iPhone.

However, when I embed the HTML link in the email itself, it gives problems.

On some email clients like Gmail app (web/mobile) and Outlook mobile app, the "Click here" appears as plain text in the email. Upon inspecting the page on gmail.com, I noticed that the ***href*** attribute was missing.

On some other email clients, like Thunderbird on Ubuntu, Edison Mail app on iPhone, the link showed up fine and worked perfectly.

Note: the email recipient is a gmail address.

As the link works fine in some clients, it rules out the possibility of an issue with

- the email delivery service - sendgrid
- the recipient's email service provider (gmail)

I replaced **&** with **&** follows by **amp;** in href, but the discrepancy persists.

I am not able to understand the reason for this.

Is there is a way to achieve this functionality, irrespective of the email client in which we open the email?

Note: A `mailto` is working fine in href,i.e., it shows up as a hyperlink, For e.g.,

```
<a href='mailto:xyz@example.com'>Click here</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've been able to research, Gmail and Outlook do NOT allow `<a href="sms:"` links. I haven't directly tested this with Outlook, but with Gmail, the link is stripped of the  tag and becomes plain HTML text, like you say. No workaround that I know of.

I realize this isn't *ideal*, but assuming you are sending this email to someone who primarily uses a smartphone to read emails (otherwise why have the SMS link), you can simply write: "Shoot me a text at 555-555-5555."