# What is the working SMS uri schema for modern iOS?

Tags: html, ios, url, uri

There are a few questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link)) ([2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link/13138273)), [blog posts](http://blog.julianklotz.de/the-sms-uri-scheme/), and apple forum threads, with some solutions for this question with older versions of iOS, but I can't find anything about iOS 12 onwards (or even anything in the last ~5 years).

The below HTML produces a link which, on Android, opens the SMS with a pre-populated recipient and message body:

```
<a href="sms:+61411111111;?&body=Hello">Press me to sms</a>
```

On iOS 12 and 14 (default Safari / Messages apps) the `body` populates, but the recipient does not.

I've tried every variation I can find. They pretty much all work on Android.

None work on iOS 12 or 14. I haven't yet tested other versions, but based on the older threads, at least some of these used to work on iOS 8 and earlier.

```
<a href="sms:+61411111111?&body=Hello">Press me to sms</a>      // Populates body, no recipient
<a href="sms://+61411111111?&body=Hello">Press me to sms</a>    // Attempts safari web navigation
<a href="sms:/+61411111111?&body=Hello">Press me to sms</a>     // Attempts safari web navigation
<a href="sms:+61411111111;?&body=Hello">Press me to sms</a>     // Populates body, no recipient
<a href="sms:+61411111111;?body=Hello">Press me to sms</a>      // No body, no recipient
<a href="sms:+61411111111;&body=Hello">Press me to sms</a>      // Populates body, no recipient
<a href="sms:+61411111111;?&body=Hello">click me to sms</a>     // Populates body, no recipient
<a href="sms:61411111111;?&body=Hello">click me to sms</a>      // Populates body, no recipient
<a href="sms:0411111111;?&body=Hello">click me to sms</a>       // Populates body, no recipient
<a href="sms:0411111111">click me to sms</a>                    // Populates nothing
```