# Link sms on chrome, edge or other on pc/windows

Tags: windows, hyperlink, sms, smartphone

As we can see from this topic
[How to pre-populate the sms body text via an html link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link)
it is possible to generate sms links that work perfectly on smartphones.
But when I click on it on my browser while I'm on the pc running windows 10, nothing happens. The link is simply ignored even though it is totally abnormal.
Don't tell me that this is normal, NO! There is the application "My phone" which is installed and which makes it possible to send sms with the PC, to answer them, to see the notifications or even the photos of the smartphone. So the pc can send sms via this application which is from microsoft and I am on a microsoft system. I often use it to write my sms. But the browser (chrome for example, but also edge for example) does not work while they should transmit the request to the application "my phone".
My question is :
How can I add parameters to the system so that it works?
It seems like such an obvious question that I'm surprised I haven't seen similar ones on the internet despite long searches.
Thanks to those who will answer and especially to those who will give a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/80650/8997916

Comment: This is lazyness on MS part of not registering in the registry