# Nuxt.js <a href="sms:"> is trying to parse it as a Nuxt Link

Tags: javascript, html, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt to build a mobile app, everything is working really well, but I have a link for SMS that i'm trying to setup

`<a href="sms:+12223334444?body=hello%20world%21>Send SMS</a>`

I also tried

`<a href="sms://+12223334444?body=hello%20world%21>Send SMS</a>`

I do understand using the right formatting for iOS or Android, but when I build out the application and 'click this link', it opens a Nuxt Route and says, "route cannot be found". Clearly this isn't a Nuxt route, so I'm trying to find out how to use the native functionality of this feature when on mobile.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Hi, did you tried that one? https://stackoverflow.com/a/19126326/8816585 This should not be anyhow related to nuxt per-se.

Comment: @kissu Hey, yeah that's where I initially got the data. I'm currently playing around with this, in case anyone else is interested. So far so good. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@byteowls/capacitor-sms