Failed to launch 'sms:<PhoneNumber>' because the scheme does not have a registered handler [FOR DESKTOP]
I am struggling with the error "Failed to launch 'sms:+4733378901' because the scheme does not have a registered handler." when clicking the SMS link. The href of the SMS link is "sms:+4733378901". Email (mailto:) and Call ("tel:") are working but sms is not working.
HTML code
<p><a href="sms:+4733378901">+47 333 78 901</a></p>

I am facing this issue in all browsers e.g. Chrome, Firefox and IE.

Look through the answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480462/how-to-pre-populate-the-sms-body-text-via-an-html-link

Sorry, I forgot to mention it. I need it to work on the desktop.

IETF  does specify the sms scheme, so it is obviously valid. However, your computer would still need a handler to handle that scheme.
A user in the Google Messages community asked the same question and the accepted response was "I am not aware of any handler that does this."
If you do have a handler and you want this to work just for your pc, try Registering an Application to a URI Scheme.
